# SKLearn PCA explained_variance_ration cumsum gives array of 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, data-analysis, variance

I have a problem with PCA. I read that PCA needs clean numeric values. I started my analysis with a dataset called `trainDf` with shape `(1460, 79)`.

I did my data cleaning and processing by removing empty values, imputing and dropping columns and I got a dataframe `transformedData` with shape `(1458, 69)`.

Data cleaning steps are:

1. `LotFrontage` imputing with mean value
2. `MasVnrArea` imputing with 0s (less than 10 cols)
3. Ordinal encoding for categorical columns
4. `Electrical` imputing with most frequent value

I found outliers with IQR and got `withoutOutliers` with shape `(1223, 69)`.

After this, I looked at histograms and decided to apply `PowerTransformer` on some features and `StandardScaler` on others and I got `normalizedData`.

Now I tried doing PCA and I got this:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(transformedData)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

the output of this PCA is the following:

```
[0.67454179 0.8541084  0.98180307 0.99979932 0.99986346 0.9999237
 0.99997091 0.99997985 0.99998547 0.99999044 0.99999463 0.99999719
 0.99999791 0.99999854 0.99999909 0.99999961 0.99999977 0.99999988
 0.99999994 0.99999998 0.99999999 1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.        ]
```

[image: PCA1]

Then I tried:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(withoutOutliers)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

out:

```
[0.68447278 0.86982875 0.99806386 0.99983727 0.99989606 0.99994353
 0.99997769 0.99998454 0.99998928 0.99999299 0.9999958  0.99999775
 0.99999842 0.99999894 0.99999932 0.99999963 0.9999998  0.9999999
 0.99999994 0.99999998 0.99999999 1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.        ]
```

[image: PCA2]

Finally:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(normalizedData)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

Out:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

[image: PCA3]

How is it possible that the last execution gives such an output?

Here are data distributions

`transformedData`

[image: transformedData hist]

`withoutOutliers`

[image: withoutOutliers hist]

`normalizedData`

[image: normalizedData hist]

I'll add any further data if necessary, thanks in advance to any who can help!

Comment: You may need to normalize the (entire) data. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca

Comment: The `PowerTransformer` already do it, and the rest of the data are already on scale

Comment: @Peter i added histograms about the data I have, any tips?

Comment: Again: you did not put the variables on the same scale https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385775/normalizing-vs-scaling-before-pca

Comment: I moved StandardScaler out of my column transformer and put it as last Pipeline stage, now PCA gives a curve instead of a 1 arrays. Thanks @Peter , if you put your comment as an aswer I'll mark it as correct answer!

Comment: Really happy to help and thx for your reply. I‘ll add a proper anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [PCA](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/94614/71442) it is really important to put all (!) features on the [same scale](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80624/how-do-standardization-and-normalization-impact-the-coefficients-of-linear-model/80634#80634) using standardization, e.g. using [standard.scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), i.e. having mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

Also see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385775/normalizing-vs-scaling-before-pca) posts.

The reason for this is that PCA looks at the variance explained by the different features. So in order to make the features comparable, standardization is required.